# User Defined Runtime Attributes and Associated Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard, associated-object

I'm currently trying to use User Defined Runtime Attributes in Xcode 6 with the following algorithm:

1. Add custom properties to UIView class using Associated Objects

   ```
   #define ASSOCIATED_OBJECT_GETTER_AND_SETTER(propertyType, propertyName, propertyNameWithCapital, associationType)   \
   -(void)set##propertyNameWithCapital:(propertyType)_value                                                            \
   {                                                                                                                   \
       objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(propertyName), _value, associationType);                               \
   }                                                                                                                   \
   -(propertyType)propertyName                                                                                         \
   {                                                                                                                   \
       return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(propertyName));                                                 \
   }                                                                                                                   \                                       

   @interface eMyTags : NSObject
   @property (nonatomic) NSString* name;
   @end

   @implementation eMyTags
   @synthesize name;
   @end

   @interface UIView (MyTags)
   @property (nonatomic) eMyTags* myTags;
   @property (nonatomic) NSString* myName;
   @end

   @implementation UIView (MyTags)
   @dynamic myTags, myName;
   ASSOCIATED_OBJECT_GETTER_AND_SETTER(eMyTags*, myTags, MyTags, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
   ASSOCIATED_OBJECT_GETTER_AND_SETTER(NSString*, myName, MyName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
   @end
   ```
2. Set values of these properties through Xcode storyboard
   [image]
3. Access these properties in code during runtime

   ```
   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSLog(@"myName: %@", view.myName);
       NSLog(@"myTags.name: %@", view.myTags.name);
   }
   ```

When i compile and run the output is:

```
myName: bla
myTags.name: (null)
```

**So why `myTags.name` is not set? What did i miss? Can't i set User Defined Runtime Attributes of custom types?**

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @DaniA  I have found the solution for my specific problem, but i don't even remember what was the actual problem and how i solved this :) It was 2 years ago and i haven't code on objective-c for a long time since then. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `myTags` is not allocated in the memory and nor initialised. On the other hand, the value @"bla" is a string literal which is actually an instance of an `NSString` and points to a location in memory.

Comment: Oh i see now... So when should i initialize `myTags`? Or is it impossible to use custom types like this?

Comment: Runtime attributes in xcode are used to set values for UIElements which are in turn allocated and initialized when the nib is loaded. http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/30/xcode-runtime-attributes/

Comment: Loading and initializing custom objects is not possible through this approach. You need to write code for that :).